# React Material UI - Radio buttons in list are all selectable

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, material-ui, radio-group

Hey I want to have a list of Radio Buttons for each item in my array. Currently my project is working fine, but not the radio buttons because all of them are selectable.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to set the name attribute in order to select only one

Here is the fiddle : https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-brown-m7f4k

```
              <label>
                {answer.text}
                {question.single ? (
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    onChange={onChange(question.id, answer.id)}
                  />
                ) : (
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    name={`radio_${question.id}`}
                    onChange={onClick(question.id, answer.id)}
                  />
                )}
              </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

you tagged material-ui but the sandbox does not seem to use material-ui.

anyway, in material-ui you can use RadioGroup to make one of the Radio Buttons selectable.

just like this example from material-ui documentation:

```
<FormControl component="fieldset">
  <FormLabel component="legend">Gender</FormLabel>
  <RadioGroup aria-label="gender" name="gender1" value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
    <FormControlLabel value="female" control={<Radio />} label="Female" />
    <FormControlLabel value="male" control={<Radio />} label="Male" />
  </RadioGroup>
</FormControl>
```

and they have another way to do it using Standalone Radio Buttons

check :https://material-ui.com/components/radio-buttons/#standalone-radio-buttons

---

if you are using HTML Radio Buttons not material-ui

then use the **name** property inside the inputs

just like this:

```
  <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
  <label for="male">Male</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
  <label for="female">Female</label><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the name attribute with the same value.

For example :

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <p>Please select your gender: <b>(With same name)</b></p>
  <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
  <label for="male">Male</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
  <label for="female">Female</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="other">
  <label for="other">Other</label>

  <br>  

<p>Please select your gender:<b>(With diferent name)</b> </p>
  <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender1" value="male">
  <label for="male">Male</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender2" value="female">
  <label for="female">Female</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender3" value="other">
  <label for="other">Other</label>
  
</form>
```